# DB2 SQL statement - is it possible to A) declare a temporary table B) populate it with data then C) run a select statement against it?

Tags: sql, db2

I have read only access to a DB2 database and i want to create an "in flight/on the fly" or temporary table which only exists within the SQL, then populate it with values, then compare the results against an existing table.

So far I am trying to validate the premise and have the following query compiling but failing to pick anything up with the select statement.

Can anyone assist me with what I am doing wrong or advise on what I am attempting to do is possible? (Or perhaps a better way of doing things)

Thanks
Justin

```
--Create a table that only exists within the query 
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEMPEVENT (EVENT_TYPE INTEGER);

--Insert a value into the temporary table
INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMPEVENT (EVENT_TYPE) VALUES ('1');

--Select all values from the temporary table
SELECT * FROM SESSION.TEMPEVENT;

--Drop the table so the query can be run again
DROP TABLE SESSION.TEMPEVENT;
```

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the syntax diagram of the [DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003272.html) statement, you may note the following block:

```
     .-ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS---.      
--●--+-------------------------+--●----------------------------  
     '-ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS-'
```

This means that `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` is default behavior. If you issue your statements with the `autocommit` mode turned on, the `commit` statement issued automatically after each statement implicitly, which deletes all the rows in your DGTT.
If you want DB2 not to delete rows in DGTT upon commit, you have to explicitly specify the `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` clause in the DGTT declaration.